# Is there a method replace for mboxFactoryDefault.addOnLoad(action) in adobe Target Standard (at.js)

Tags: adobe, ab-testing

I am looking for a method replacement for mboxFactoryDefault.addOnLoad(action) that returns all the parameters passed during an mbox call (this used to be available in earlier versions of mbox.js) in an adobe target standard response (at.js response) which I can use.

I have checked the available API but did not find the replacement.

Looking for help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check at.js custom events:

https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/target/ov2/cmp_at.js_Functions.html

The event `adobe.target.event.REQUEST_SUCCEEDED` returns a lot of useful information about the call:

```
document.addEventListener(adobe.target.event.REQUEST_SUCCEEDED, function(event) {
  console.log('Event', event);
});
```